# Ошибка - Привязка SOAP 1.1 не найдена

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

Пытаюсь преобразовать WSDL в классы C# командой wsdl main.wsdl /l:C#, содержимое main.wsdl

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5. -->
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5. -->
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" 
    xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
    xmlns:tns="http://schemas.sitels.ru/SPA.Services/v001" 
    xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" 
    xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" 
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
    xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:soapbind="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:uddi="urn:uddi-org:api_v2" 
    targetNamespace="https://cwmp-data-models.broadband-forum.org/cwmp-1-4.xsd" name="cwmp">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="https://cwmp-data-models.broadband-forum.org/cwmp-1-4.xsd" schemaLocation="1-4.wsdl"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

При попытке преобразования получаю предупреждение :

```
    Внимание! Эта ссылка не соответствует WS-I Basic Profile v1.1.
Привязка SOAP 1.1 не найдена: Basic Profile 1.1 WS-I содержит рекомендации по реализации, в которых описываются принципы совместного использования ряда спецификаций базовых веб-служб при организации взаимодействия веб-служб. Для Profile 1.1 это такие спецификации, как SOAP 1.1, WSDL 1.1, UDDI 2.0, XML 1.0 и XML Schema.

Для получения дополнительных сведений о WS-I Basic Profile v1.1 см. спецификацию
по адресу http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html.

Внимание! классы не созданы.
Получены предупреждения. Для получения дополнительных сведений см. комментарии в созданном исходном коде.
```

Утилита генерирует файл, который содержит только информацию о том, что он был сгенерирован утилитой "wsdl.exe", никаких дополнительных сведений об ошибке в нём нет.

Answer (score 0):

Предоставленный вами wsdl не содержит никакой информации о самом сервисе, его операциях и конечных точках, там есть только ссылка на xsd-схему. Причём xsd-схема имеет расширение .wsdl, что крайне подозрительно. Отсюда и пустой файл: wsdl не содержит никакой полезной информации и генерировать нечего.